# Задание: Нужно разработать приложение, которое будет обрабатывать Excel таблицу, а после вычислять корреляцию

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

1. Создал форму
2. расположил на ней menuStrip и в меню кнопку открыть
3. написал алгоритм выбора и обработки Excel таблицы(код ниже)
4. надо написать алгоритм для кнопки, который будет вычислять корреляцию полученных данных из Excel таблицы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


using OfficeOpenXml;
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private double[,] excelTable;
        private int totalRows = 0;
        private int totalColumns = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult res = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                
                if (res == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName));

                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];
                    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
                        List<string> list = row.ToList<string>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                        {
                            excelTable[rowIndex - 1, i] = Convert.ToDouble(list[i].Replace('-', ','));

                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(excelTable[i, j]) + "     ";

                        }
                        richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Файл не выбран");
                }



            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

этот код считывает данные таблицы.

Comment: предоставьте свои нароботки, что не получается, какие ошибки получаете. [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1286373/edit)

Comment: у меня нет наработок, я не знаю как это сделать. На данный момент программка просто считывает таблицу Excel и переводит ее в двух мерный массив

Comment: Ну допустим. А что такое "считать корреляцию" -- какая это формула вы понимаете? А то похоже пока на "возьми то, не знаю что - посчитай это, не скажу как".

Comment: Хорошо: ваши мысли, логику, возможный способ реализации. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) можно почитать почему я задаю эти вопросы.

Comment: я просто не знаю как объяснить нормально.....